# How to execute a shell script from anywhere on my server?

Tags: shell-script, command-line

So basically I have a JS app that is inside a directory in `/var/lib/app/`.  To start this node app I execute a start script `startapp.sh` from inside the directory. Now I need it to start at boot time, so I created an upstart job in my Ubuntu server inside `/etc/init` and gave the absolute path of the `startapp.sh`, to get trigger at boot time.

But whenever I try to execute any script that triggers `startup.sh`, it fails to start as it depends on an activator file to start, which is inside the `/var/lib/app/` directory. I have exported the path in `.bashrc`, but still I am unable to execute the job from anywhere in Ubuntu server, except the `/var/lib/app/` directory.

How can I execute a shell script from anywhere on my server?

Comment: In your startapp.sh you should use the absolute path to node and the app.js

Comment: Note: using file extensions is discouraged for executables: Consider that everything that uses it needs to unnecessarily know what language it is written in, then consider that you rewrite it in a different language, what consequence will this have for the callers of this program? (The same could be said for data: gif vs png vs jpeg).

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `/var/lib/app/` directory to your PATH, not `/var/lib/app/startapp.sh`.

To do this **permanently**, first take a look at your PATH environment variable by entering this command:

`echo $PATH`

The output you will get, will be something like:

`/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/:usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin/ ...`

You shouldn't alter the order, so while exporting you should use `PATH="$PATH:/..."` to **append** your new path to the previous original path that was just shown.

Open your `.bashrc` (assuming it is called from `~/.profile` on OSX) via `vi` or whatsoever editor you like and add this line:

`export PATH="$PATH:/your/absolute/path"`

You should add your **absolute** path, it means the directory that your apps are put under so when you then type the apps' filenames, it just gets executed.  For example, when you enter `pwd`, it's run from `/bin/` directory - what you can see in your PATH environment variable -, so the script is `/bin/pwd`. To see it, enter `which pwd` in your bash.
I think your absolute path is `/var/lib/app/` if there is no directory under it and your apps are there.

This will work if you do it properly, but if it did not, the easiest thing is to move your written apps from `/var/lib/app/` to `/bin/`.

```
$ cd /var/lib/app/
$ mv * /bin
```

Answer (score 0):

To read data from the file that an executable is stored in:

```
#!/bin/bash

old_dir="$(pwd)"
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
this_dir="$(pwd)"
cd "${old_dir}"
unset old_dir

# read from where executable is stored
echo "${this_dir}/data"
# read for present working directory
echo "$(pwd)"
```